# Chaotic Highpass Filter Output

Tags: rf, circuit-design, signal, transmitter, high-pass-filter

I'm trying to build an RF transmitter circuit using LTSpice. Built a diode balanced signal mixer connected to a high pass filter to distinguish high frequency from low frequency. However, I'm kinda running into a problem with the output signal of the high-pass filter. The output voltage level is not stable.

1. Circuit:

   [image: List item]
2. High-pass Filter Output:

   [image: High-Pass filter output]
3. Mixer Output:

   [image]

The question is if the output signal of the high-pass filter whether correct or not. If not what causes the distortion and how can I fix it? If the output signal is just how it is supposed to be, can I directly connect it to the antenna after amplifying? Or do I need another circuit block?

Is the chaotic-looking ac wave I've got as high-pass filter output can be transmitted correctly by the antenna? How voltage level of the RF signal affects antenna transmission? And what happens if the voltage level is not stable? Does the receiver receive the same chaotic signal or does it just take the frequency with no voltage distortion?

-Edit-

4. Bandpass Filter Output:

[image]

1nf 19ohm High-pass filter/ 9ohm 1nf Low-pass filter

-Edit(2)-

5. RLC Bandpass Filter Output

[image]

80ohm 1nf 300nH

Comment: Try bandpass filtering the output with enough BW to cover the sidebands. Basically it looks about right.

Comment: Well, It got more acceptable after the bandpass filter consists of 1nf + 79 ohm as a high-pass filter and 15ohm + 1nf as a low-pass filter. But I still couldn't get rid of the low-frequency wave. I guess I'm having trouble with the values of the components. (also tried 18ohm and 9ohm)

Comment: A proper bandpass filter is needed made from a resistor feeding a parallel LC. Try messing with this [calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RCL%20BPF/RCL%20BPF.html) to adjust L and C to the correct values. I estimate L is 1 uH and C is 1.59 nF. The calculator is from my basic website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr0Hg.png

Comment: RLC Bandpass filter did quite a good job.  While showing high impedance to other frequencies lets 8.5mhz frequency pass flawlessly. I'll be researching RLC Bandpass to make voltage levels stable.

Comment: You have a carrier frequency of 4MHz and baseband frequency of 4.5MHz. What transmit (suppressed carrier) frequency and bandwidth did you want? Do you want to transmit both sidebands or just one (which one)?

Comment: 8.5mhz rf (bandwidth) to be transmitted(both sidebands). IF signal(baseband) as receiver mixer output.